# Refreshing Table data without UpdatePanel using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a dataTable that get populated on Page Load.
I am populating my table on the client side using a foreach on that dataTable.
Now the user will enter a few search criteria and I want to once again get the data and re-display the results.

I wanted to avoid using an Update Panel.
So I created a static method in my code behind to do the necessary retrieval from the database while accepting the parameters passed in from the ajax call.
I created my ajax call in my javascript and passed in my data.

The ajax makes the call with the correct data, and my data is retrieved from the database.  My dataTable value is set.  Now I can't quite figure out how to update my table with the new data.

It is almost as if I need to re-fire the foreach section of my html code.

Any ideas?

---

My javascript function

```
$('#btnRunSearch').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/GetInspectionData",
                data: "{'insp':'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 
                       'searchVal':'', 
                       'startDate':'2013-03-01', 
                       'endDate':'2013-04-01', 
                       'agent':'', 
                       'status':0, 'sortexp':''}",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {




                }
            });

        });
```

My Html

```
<tbody>
   <%
      foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dtInspections.Rows)
      {
    %>
      <tr>
        <td>
```

Code Behind Server Side

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool GetInspectionData(string insp, 
               string searchVal, string startDate, string endDate, 
               string agent, int status, string sortexp)
    {

        // this.SetFiltersToSession();

        int intCurrentCompany = login.GetCurrentlyLoggedInInspectorCompany();


        Guid inspector = new Guid(insp);
        DataSet ds = Bizlogic.cBizLogicBaseClass.GetGenDataAccess().
           GetDataSet("usp_Get_SearchInspections", "Inspections", 
           true, 
           intCurrentCompany, 
           inspector, 
           searchVal, 
           startDate, 
           endDate, 
           agent, 
           status, 
           sortexp);

         //dtInspections is the dataTable that is used to populate the table
        dtInspections = ds.Tables[0];



        return true;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do this is to put the html for your table in to a separate view from everything else and then use the jQuery .load function.  This will allow your ajax call to load the table in to the div each time that it is called.

You can find documentation for the load function [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').load("Home.aspx/GetInspectionData", 
                     "{'insp':'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 
                     'searchVal':'', 
                     'startDate':'2013-03-01', 
                     'endDate':'2013-04-01', 
                     'agent':'', 
                     'status':0, 'sortexp':''}",
                     function() {
    //
    //code for complete function goes here
    //
});
```

If I did not explain well enough or you have more questions please let me know.

Comment: Okay so in my javascript function I would have to create javascript to create an html table?  As well I have noticed that the dtInspections value changed on the server side, but it did not update on the client side.  As I tried to display the number of rows on my success call back function.

Comment: Nope, you make a separate page completely.  So you'd have another aspx page somewhere with your table in it and then you use .load to load that page in to your container div.  For lack of a better example its kind of like you are turning your container div in to a browser for that other page.

Comment: Its more like a dynamically loaded partial view if you know what partial views are.

Comment: So I've moved my table into a new aspx file.  As well created a webmethod in that new aspx file.  However when I make the call ($'#container').load("PartialHome.aspx/GetInspectionData", etc. it does not hit my server side method.

Answer (score 0):

Changing server-side variables through an ajax call doesn't automatically update the UI. The point of ajax is to hit the server without the page reloading. That is part of what makes an UpdatePanel nice - you can do server-side updates and it handles updating the UI for you.

If you want to use ajax without an update panel, you'll need your WebMethod to return the data, then use javascript to repopulate the table.